# How to pass parameter from C# code to JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, parameters

JavaScript function:

```
function WelcomeMessageMaster(clientID) {
    alert("ClientID = " + clientID);
}
```

C# code:

```
clientStageCommand = new ClientStepCommand
{
    CommandType = ClientStageCommandType.Eval,
    Argument = "WelcomeMessageMaster"/("/" + this.Grid.UniqueID + ""/)""
};
```

But, there's compiler error that says something's wrong with brackets. I'm not sure where to put quotation marks.

Comment: Excuse me, it's similar, but not the same. I haven't posted whole code. Could you open it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clientStageCommand = new ClientStepCommand
{
    CommandType = ClientStageCommandType.Eval,
    Argument = string.Format(@"WelcomeMessageMaster(""{0}"")", this.Grid.UniqueID)
};
```

Comment: I've just posted the whole code above. Could you take a look at it, please?